# Identification of a basic-looking black helmet with a big logo painted on the back used in a John Doe ad

Tags: motorcycle, crash-helmet

I'm currently getting my motorcycle gear together. I stumbled across a helmet which would look pretty nice alongside the rest of my outfit. However, I can't really find the product or something similar looking.

The helmet was in this ad:

[image: John Doe ad]
<sub>From [John Doe Look #2 2017](http://www.ridejohndoe.com/look-2.html)</sub>

Is anybody able to identify this black basic-looking helmet based on this picture?

---

***Note***: I've created [a meta question](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/is-it-on-topic-to-ask-about-identification-of-a-specific-equipment-shown-in-a-pi) before posting this to clarify whether such questions are on-topic or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a [Bell Bullitt](https://the-cafe-racer.com/bell-bullitt-helmet-solid-black?gclid=Cj0KCQjw8vnMBRDgARIsACm_BhIUFWBUEkE0IHrLVZk5eACyeJ_ihvH0DH3p7msnqwcTNTC018MHtroaAnZsEALw_wcB) retro helmet with custom paint job on it.

It has:

- the same shape visor
- the round vents above the visor
- same "hinge" mechanism
- round detail below the hinge at the ear

[image]